How to find out which db objects are accessed using database link
I have 2 db links defined in my schema and there are around 20 to 30 views that are defined using this 2 db links, now I can find out which all tables can be accessed using this db links but it not necessary that all the tables that this db links points might used in the views,
My question is how to find out all the tables and other db objects like mvs that are used in views that use this 2 db links.
I am expecting list of db objects that this db link points to and used in the views.

Which dbms are you using? (The  tag is for ISO/ANSI SQL language related questions. But you're having a product specific problem.)

I am using oracle 11g
